# ASP.NET MVC 1.0 AfterBuilding Views fails on TFS Build

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tfsbuild

I've upgraded from ASP.NET MVC Beta to 1.0 and did the following changes to the MVC project (as descibed in the RC release notes):

```
<Project ...>
  ...
  <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
  ...
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\$(ProjectName)" />
  </Target>
  ...
</Project>
```

While the build runs fine on our local dev boxes, it fails under TFS 2008 Build with "Could not load type 'xxx.MvcApplication'", see below build log:

```
...
using "AspNetCompiler" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "AspNetCompiler"

  Command:
  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe -v temp -p D:\Builds\xxx\Continuous\TeamBuild\Sources\UI\xxx.UI.Dashboard\\..\xxx.UI.Dashboard 
  The "AspNetCompiler" task is using "aspnet_compiler.exe" from "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe".
  Utility to precompile an ASP.NET application
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/temp/global.asax(1): error ASPPARSE: Could not load type 'xxx.UI.Dashboard.MvcApplication'.
  The command exited with code 1.

Done executing task "AspNetCompiler" -- FAILED.
...
```

MVC 1.0 is installed on TFS and the solution compiles when built within a Visual Studio instance on the same TFS server.

How can I resolve this TFS Build issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that the AspNetCompiler MSBuild task used within the AfterBuild target of an ASP.NET MVC project expects to reference the dll's in the bin folder of the Web project.

On a desktop build the bin folder is where you would expect it under your source tree.

However TFS Teambuild compiles the output of your source to a different directory on the build server. When the AspNetCompiler task starts it cannot find the bin directory to reference the required DLL and you get the exception.

Solution is to modify the AfterBuild target of the MVC Project to be as follows:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'false'" VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\$(ProjectName)" />
    <AspNetCompiler Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false'" VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(PublishDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)" />
  </Target>
```

This change enables you to compile Views on both the desktop, and the TFS build server.

Comment: That worked. Hope MS changes the .csproj file template accordingly.

Comment: thats crazy why they haven't fixed this!! ??

Comment: I'll check with the TFS TeamBuild team, but I'm not sure if we can "fix" this. This answer hard-codes a TFS specific directory structure  "_PublishedWebsites". What if you're not using TFS TeamBuild to build your site but using something else? That would likely break.

By moving this build to TFS Team Build, you've customized your project. You'll need to update the paths accordingly, which is what the person did who answered this question.

Comment: I've detailed a better solution to this problem in my answer below.

Comment: Jim's solution is the one we used in ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update. See my comment to his answer.

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed my similar problem!

Comment: This involves another hardcoding in some way while Jim's solution is more generic.

Answer (score 181):

Actually, there's a better solution to this problem. I've tested it with VS/TFS 2010 but it should also work with VS/TFS 2008.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

I'm going to work with the MVC team to update their project template to to use this approach along with a custom target (rather than overriding AfterBuild).

I've published a blog post on How to [Turn on Compile-time View Checking for ASP.NET MVC projects in TFS Build 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/20/turn-on-compile-time-view-checking-for-asp-net-mvc-projects-in-tfs-build-2010.aspx).

Comment: And if your solution contains more than one web project, how will this work? That is why I built the path myself...

Comment: Should work fine with multiple web projects - WebProjectOutputDir is distinct for each project.

Comment: This ended up being the solution we used. Thanks Jim! It's been fixed in ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update. See my blog post here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx

Comment: Strange, my project was apparently new enough that I already had the physical path set to `$(WebProjectOutputDir)`, yet I was still getting the error after setting `MvcBuildViews` to true. Adding `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` was the only thing that seemed to solve the problem. This makes me wonder what my WebProjectOutputDir is set to...Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Followup: I seemed to require this modified version of your Target block: 
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'" DependsOnTargets="CleanWebsitesPackage;CleanWebsitesPackageTempDir;CleanWebsitesTransformParametersFiles;">
     <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
  </Target> [apologies for the formatting]

Comment: This works with msbuild v14 but fails with msbuild v15.1:
`$ aspnet_compiler.exe -v temp `
`$ error: ASPRUNTIME: '/temp' is not a valid IIS application`

I haven't found a solution yet for msbuild v15.1

Comment: Using VS 2017 with MVC 5, I had to restrict the Physical Path further. By default, `$(WebProjectOutputDir)` points to the project's folder.  We had something that would create copies of revisioned files (using a CMS), which were not included in the project.  We ultimately went with `PhysicalPath=$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Views`, but now we'll have to add a new Target if we add new View folders (such as for Areas).

Comment: What's the best way to do this with MVC 5 in VS 2017? None of this works.

Comment: the link in the answer is not working anymore :( do you have the right one?

Answer (score 3):

Jim Lamb's solution didn't work for us when I built our web .csproj with

```
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true;PipelineDependsOnBuild=False
```

because the target was being executed `AfterBuild` and the application has not been copied into the `WebProjectOutputDir` yet. (BTW, I pass those properties to the web project build cos I want the build to create a OutDir folder with only my binaries and cshtml files suitable for zipping, ie not an in-place build)

To get around this issue and honour the intent of his original target, I did the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OnAfter_WPPCopyWebApplication>
        MvcBuildViews;
    </OnAfter_WPPCopyWebApplication>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant you changed the following setting in the .csproj file:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

The setting you posted in your question shouldn't be touched.
If it works on your local machine, then obviously you can pre-build an ASP.NET MVC application.

I think you need to track down what's different between your TFS build environment and your local VS machines. Maybe it's using a different version of MsBuild or something.

Try performing both builds with verbose output and compare the two to see what's different.

Comment: The paths etc used in TFS appear to be completely different from those on my local machine and in source control, therefore you have to specify different locations for each scenario.

Comment: @haacked how come this was never updated in the template? its quite confusing the first time you run up against it. especially all those new 'TFS Basic' users not used to dealing with things like this

Answer (score 0):

We are still testing this out, but it appears that you can move the false/true from the  tag set, into the property group for your DEBUG build version, you can still set it to true and MSBuild will compile (assuming MSBuild TfsBuild.proj file is setup to use something other than debug configuration). You will need to edit the csproj file using Notepad to accomplish this.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
    ....
```

You need to move the MVCBuildViews tag from the default property group above, to the debug configuration property group (below). Again, when we get the TFS / MSBuild setup, I'll try to post the step we added to our TFSBuild.proj file in TFS.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems similar to the one talked about here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/07/02/team-build-and-web-deployment-projects.aspx
it seems the invocation of aspnet_compiler.exe fails to locate the binaries because the are not in the bin folder of the MVC project on the build machine. I haven't worked out a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. The $(PublishDir) parameter did not point to the correct location. Instead I had to use:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'false'" VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\$(ProjectName)" />
    <AspNetCompiler Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false'" VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Well as long as the answer pointed you in the right direction, then its all good. OutDir on my setup points to a root build dir that contains all assemblies from the other projects within the solution, the PublishDir points to the Web Application projects contained with in the solution. Does your solution contain other projects than just the MVC Web App?

Comment: Yes it contains multiple projects, and yes your answer did point me in the right direction. I'm not sure why the $PublishDir works for you and not me, but I'm not too hung up over it, the fix was straightforward and I just thought I'd put it out there if anyone else runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had some old folders in my source control that were not visible in the Solution.

Answer (score -6):

You cannot pre-build an ASP.NET MVC application.