# receiving "error ASPPARSE: Could not load type ..." error with msbuild on MVC webapp

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, configuration-management

We have CCNET and msbuild creating our regular builds.  I am trying to update our process so msbuild creates zipped deployment packages and msdeploy sends them out to the target IIS7 web servers.  I was having trouble doing the end to end solution, so for testing I'm trying to just call msbuild from the command line for now.  I execute this statement:

```
msbuild /target:Build;Package /P:Configuration=Staging;OutDir=D:\Builds\Viper.ProdSupport\MSDeployPkg\ /verbosity:diagnostic D:\builds\ViperPortal.ProdSupport\Code\Viper\Viper.UI.MVC\Viper.UI.MVC.csproj
```

and I get this error:

/temp/global.asax(1): error ASPPARSE: Could not load type 'Viper.UI.MVC.MvcApplication'. [D:\builds\ViperPortal.ProdSupport\Code\Viper\Viper.UI.MVC\Viper.UI.MVC.csproj]

Oh, and for our specs: .NET4, MVC3, IIS7/Win2k8 64bit for web server.  Build server is Win2k8 as well, but I'm testing the scripts locally on a win 7 32bit box with ccnet and a full dev config mgmt environment setup locally.

Does anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this error?  I read some messages complaining about the aspnet compiler or changing where your bin deploys assemblies to, but none of those seemed to really apply here.  I am simply trying to call msbuild, which has been working all along til now.  We have a custom msbuild script for our solution.  I tried using both that and the mvc csproj file as the build configuration file.  Please help!  Thanks!

Comment: One possibility is you are missing one of the dependencies required to load the assembly. Try using [FusLogVw tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx) to figure out the name of missing assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Seva!  I already found the issue here, but I will definitely try that tool to fix future issues!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 1.0 AfterBuilding Views fails on TFS Build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755645/asp-net-mvc-1-0-afterbuilding-views-fails-on-tfs-build)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this happens if you've set to precompile views, i.e. you changed:

```
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

to

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

This is because MSBuild throws the output to different places than Visual Studio might, so you should change the folder on which the precompiling runs on from:

```
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" />
```

to:

```
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Rowland!  I found a fix for my issue on a related post and it was similar to what you mentioned:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1098441/1073742