# ASP.NET cannnot access to windows temp folder?

Tags: asp.net, .net, temp

whenever I want to run my application from localhost
it generates the following wierd error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CVT1108: cannot open C:\Windows\TEMP\RESC1C1.tmp for writing

Source Error:



[No relevant source lines]


Source File:    Line: 0 



Show Detailed Compiler Output:

....

CVTRES : fatal error CVT1108: cannot open C:\Windows\TEMP\RESC1C1.tmp for writing
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

error CS1583: 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\449ad1a6\abc33f1b\CSCC1C0.tmp' is not a valid Win32 resource file
```

Comment: The application is probably running with "Internet Guest Account" privileges, which do not have write access to Windows' TEMP folder by default.

Comment: How can I set the account privileges?

Comment: Problem solved when I gave "CREATOR OWNER" group, Full access to this folder!

Answer (score 28):

Here are the steps to fix it:

Go to C:\Windows

Right Click the Temp folder

Click on Properties

Go to Security

Give CREATOR OWNER group full control.

Comment: +1 But note that windows might ignore the permission changes, the best way around that is to change (temporarily) the ownership to the "Creator Owner" group and then give it full permissions (note that changing ownership to the current logged-in user doesn't necessarily help)

Comment: I tried to give full rights to Creater owner but it always changes when i click apply.So later what i have done is right click temp folder and then click "Take ownership".

Answer (score 3):

for those who **cant give FULL CONTROL to c:\windows\temp like me**

**[this is how i solved]**  
1- run **cmd AS admin** (keep it open ). 
2- open task manager and  **KİLL explorer.exe.** 
3- goto previously opened **cmd. write explorer.exe  hit enter.** 
4- go to c:\windows  temp (right click)>properties ->security  
5- now you will be able to change  \IIS_IUSRS to Full Control

**note:** some application may give error about elevated exploer.exe . it will be fixed after restart.

if you dont wanna restart; 
**[take explorer.exe out of Administrator mode]** 
1- goto previosly opened task manager.  kill explorer.exe  
2- in task manager file-> start new process  write there explorer.exe 
 
3- now the  explorer.exe is in normal mode.

https://serverfault.com/questions/694184/cannot-provide-permission-to-iis-iusrs-on-c-windows-temp/731681#731681

Comment: Tnaks a lot. Allthough it looks like a Windows security issue, it solved my problem.