# Visual Studio 2010 issue to convert a Web application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, global-asax

I have a website made with **vb** and **c#**. I open the project in Visual Studio 2010 and there are no problems. 
My problems start when I try to debug it.
 I have this error:

> Could not load type 'projectName.Global

Also I need to convert it into a web application but when I do right-click on the project this option is not there.

I did all settings in IIS but I always have this error and I cant convert it

If it is not clear tell me, I will try to improve my question.

Comment: Did you try to follow this steps? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: yes but it doesnt help me so much. I must stop at this point: **In the Debug menu, click Start Debugging. Alternatively, you can press F5** because i cant start the debug

Comment: try some of this solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001/could-not-load-type-xxx-global

Comment: visual studio see my project as website and i cant convert it into a web application. Versions and paths are right. Now i try delete and save again the global.asax EDITED: it doesnt works