# Having problems deploying my .Net web application via FTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

In the past, I've had no problems uploading my web site to my hosting provider but now I'm using .Net 4.5 with Nuget packages and I'm getting errors.  Oh and now it's a web Application.

When I look at my file structure, I have 'MySite' as the parent folder, then under that I have the 'Packages' folder (which I assume is where the Nuget files I downloaded are installed).  At the same level as the Packages folder, I have another 'MySite' folder which I uploaded to the server via FTP.

Now I'm thinking that the server would need the Packages folder but I don't know where to put it.  I also thought about using the Publish feature in VS 2013 but need a .publishsettings file from my hosting provider which I do not have. 
Surely there is a way to just transfer the files via FTP?

At the moment I'm getting the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MySite.Global'.
Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MySite.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

I cannot see any problem with my Global.asax.cs file at all.

Comment: You dont actually need a publishsettings file, you can just do a publish to your local file system, then ftp the files to the target site.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

[Could not load type 'XXX.Global'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001/could-not-load-type-xxx-global)

["Could not load type [Namespace].Global" causing me grief](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005747/could-not-load-type-namespace-global-causing-me-grief)

I guess the problem is because some dll is missing or your pool of IIS is not configured corretly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'm sorry for the delay but I've had to recreate the project as a web site instead of a web application.  There was just one error after another and I had to rebuild the project every time I made a change.  It's just a small system so web site suits me fine :-).

Answer (score 0):

Based on error I think .net version is not property set in application pool.