# How to fix Global.asax.cs parser error in IIS 8?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I am migrating a web application from IIS 7 to IIS 8 and am encountering the following parser error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyAppName.Global'.

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyAppName.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

The app compiles and runs perfectly on IIS 7.  I have the app pool configured the same on IIS 8 as it was on IIS 7, but the app doesn't want to compile for me.  I have tried to remove the "Inherits" however this just sends me down a rabbit hole of errors.  It also looks like my app's .dlls are in the bin folder where they should be.  I don't appear to be missing any dependencies either.

Also, for what it's worth, this web app works when I run it on my local machine using Visual Studio 2010 but breaks when I use Visual Studio 2013 or higher with the Global.asax.cs error.

Comment: Check your targetFramework; I also wonder if Framework is registered on IIS8; Is IIs8 installed before or after framework installation?

Comment: check solutions posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005747/could-not-load-type-namespace-global-causing-me-grief and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001/could-not-load-type-xxx-global and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax

Comment: I'm not sure if the framework was installed before or after IIS, but it runs other apps with different frameworks alright. Both 2.0 and 4.0

Comment: @techspider I did reinstall/register Framework with IIS8, that did not fix the issue either.  I have tried going through each of the suggested solutions as well with no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

My projects outputpath had been set to "**bin/debug**"

Try setting it to just "**bin**"